# Getting a blank screen on implementing Search on listview

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to implement serach on my application without using actual search function.
The serach activity will initiate after the option search is clicked. But after clicking this i m getting a blank screen.

Here is my SearchActivity file

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //setContentView(R.layout.searchable); 

 // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    Toast.makeText(SearchResultsActivity.this, 
     query, 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  }

  }
```

Please help me in this code. Let me know if you need some more information.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show the code where you call the search.

Comment: case R.id.action_search:
           // Single option item is selected do something
          // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
         // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Intent sIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , SearchResultsActivity.class);
             startActivity(sIntent);
          return true;